# Lxde/lubuntu desktop pager displaying extra spaces between workspaces

Tags: lubuntu, lxde

The desktop pager on the taskbar is showing extra spaces for each workspace. It used to show only one tile per workspace. I am using Lubuntu 18.04.

[image: lxde desktop pager problem]

How do I fix this?

Comment: Hello. I added the version of lxde/ubuntu (18.04) to the question.

Comment: Did you connect a second monitor?

Comment: You know what, I have a primary monitor that I use for my laptop, with the laptop lid closed. I tried changing the lxrandr option to "turn off laptop LCD and use external monitor only" but it doesn't save. Could that be the issue?

Comment: I am not sure, since I use Xubuntu, but I think it is similar in Lubuntu. In Xubuntu, when I connect a second monitor, the workspace tile for each workspace expands to account for the second monitor. Try enabling both monitors and maximize a window in each one. Probably the windows will appear side by side in the same workspace tile.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to show the proper workspace tiles now. I enabled both monitors, then disabled the laptop monitor again by selecting the "turn off laptop LCD and use external monitor only" option and now it shows one tile per workspace. Seems like lxde reverted to the original after a system update. I will do this in the future if it changes back. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @user3140225 please consider writing your comment as an answer. You were correct (the 'space' was for the second monitor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Lubuntu 18.04 LTS (and Xubuntu as well), when a second monitor is connected, the workspace tile for each workspace expands to account for the second monitor. That is the "extra spaces between workspaces" that you observe.

Try enabling both monitors and maximize a window in each one to see the effect. The windows will appear side by side in the same workspace tile. If you disable one monitor, the workspace tile will revert back to its normal size.